# In an HTML submit button, how do I delay the submission using js?

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

User clicks a button -> button becomes disabled (and a spinner appears on top) -> form is submitted.

I tried this and it works only sometimes (inside the HTML button):

```
onclick="
this.classList.toggle('button--loading'); // triggers spinner (created in CSS)
this.disabled=true; // disabled button
this.form.submit();" // submits form
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it skips triggering the spinner and simply disables the button and submits afterwards. I am thinking that implementing a delay after the spinner is created will make it work 100% of the time, but I cannot figure it out.

Please note that I am quite a beginner with coding and really trying to find out how things work. Thanks!

Comment: using the `onclick` like that will be a mess.. anyway you may try using `setTimeout` passing the code to perform as a callback. You can find lots of suggestions both on the `click` event and `setTimeout` here on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

[Don't use inline HTML event attributes,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) like `onclick` - - this is a 25+ year old technique that won't die because people just keep copying and pasting other people's code. Instead use the modern API of [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Next, `click` is the wrong event to use with a `form`. You should be using `submit` on the `form`.

Lastly, to accomplish what you want, you'd need to cancel the native event within the `submit` handler, use a timer to cause a delay and then manually submit once the delay has passed.

Here's an example:

```js
// Set up the event handler the correct way:
const form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
  // Cancel the event
  event.preventDefault();
  
  document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
  
  // Initiate a 3 second delay with a timer
  let timer = setTimeout(function(){
    // This function's code will run after the timer's delay
    // do watever you want here. This is just an example:
    alert("time's up!");
    
    // But, after that, manually subnit the form
    form.submit();
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<form action="http://example.com" method="post">
  <button>Click to submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That is fantastic knowledge! Thank you so much.

Comment: Not enough reputation to upvote, but marking as the answer. Thanks again!